# Magento gets bought by Adobe

Tags: support, magento2, magento

Various news [articles](https://www.reuters.com/article/us-shopify-stocks/shopify-shares-down-as-rival-magento-gets-bought-by-adobe-idUSKCN1IN1FT) are circulating regarding the Magento-recently being owned by Adobe . What would be the apparent outcomes/consequences for the community/developer/freelancers and software firms , whose sole bread and butter is magento module development, themes, customization etc.

Comment: I am also really exited to know what will be the up coming changes !!
benifits/drawback don't know but what will be still question for us :)

Answer (score 6):

Magento will remain same as now.

It will remain as an Open source platform as per **[Matt Asay](https://twitter.com/mjasay) who is the Head of Developer Ecosystem for the Adobe**.

From below sources, you will get more information regarding Magento future with Adobe.

1. Check out the [tweet of @MattAsay which showers hope](https://twitter.com/mjasay/status/998930665805496321).
2. Check out [@Abobe official blog regarding acquiring of Magento](https://medium.com/adobe-io/doubling-down-on-adobes-open-platform-vision-with-magento-c9f8246e83e2).
3. [Article from Mark Lavelle](https://magento.com/blog/magento-news/adobe-to-acquire-magento) - CEO Magento.

Comment: I heard somewhere magento2 is not going to provide currency rate API free.is it right?

Comment: I don't hear this type of any news

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps one of the things that might confuse some users (especially uninformed users) is that **Magento has been rebranded to Adobe Commerce**, making a name discrepancy with this site's name.

[Magento Is Now Adobe Commerce](https://business.adobe.com/blog/the-latest/magento-is-now-part-of-adobe)

> We are excited to announce that Adobe’s acquisition of Magento is complete and Magento Commerce is now an Adobe company – part of Adobe Commerce.

Although, Adobe also still provides references to the original name in many places: [Magento, now Adobe Commerce](https://business.adobe.com/products/magento/magento-commerce.html).